# PHP Use zLib to Compress Multiple Files

Tags: php, zlib

```
$files = array("images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg"); 
foreach($files as $file){ 
    $temp = null; 
    $fp_in = fopen($file,'rb'); 
    while(!feof($fp_in)){ 
        $temp .= fread($fp_in,1024); 
    } 
    $output[$file] = $temp; 
    fclose($fp_in); 
} 

$output = implode('"',$output);

$zp = gzopen( 'sequences/backup.gz', "w9" );
gzwrite( $zp, $output );
gzclose( $zp );
```

The code above works but only one file is added to the archive. What is the best way to add multiple files to a archive using zLib?

Comment: gz is only a compression technique, not an archiving one. That's why it's common to see `.tar.gz` files on unix; `.tar` for the union of all files and the `.gz` to compress the archive.

Comment: Then the correct process would be to compress them, then unify them? Is there a way to accomplish this using zLib & PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'Tar.php';
$tar_object = new Archive_Tar("tarname.tar");
$tar_object->setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_PRINT);  // Optional error handling
$v_list = array("images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg"); 
$tar_object->createModify($v_list, "install");
  function compress( $srcFileName, $dstFileName ){
   // getting file content
   $fp = fopen( $srcFileName, "r" );
   $data = fread ( $fp, filesize( $srcFileName ) );
   fclose( $fp );
   // writing compressed file
   $zp = gzopen( $dstFileName, "w9" );
   gzwrite( $zp, $data );
   gzclose( $zp );
   echo 'success';
}
compress("tarname.tar","tarname.tar.gz");
unlink('tarname.tar');
```

Here is the updated code, with the help of Tim, thanks!